# How do global variable work in javascript (callback)?

Tags: javascript, forms, global-variables

Usually, defining a variable outside functions is enough to let it be "global". In my case, however, situation seems to be different.

```
var username = null;

function myFunction_1() {
    username="pippo";
    myobject.myfunction(function (data){ username="mickey" })
    console.log("1: ", username);
}
myFunction_1();
```

I expected this code to log "1: mickey". However, if i set the variable inside a callback function logs "1: pippo", that is setting inside the callback gets ignored.
What i'm missing? Setting variable in this way is not enough?

Comment: do you mean `myFunction2` by second?

Comment: And what is `salvaUsername`?

Comment: The problem is inthe code you did not show. If you use `<form onsubmit="myFunction_2()">` you should see "3: pippo"

Comment: yes, sorry, my error, i meant <form onsubmit="myFunction_2()">. (I'm sorry, but 2 downvotes for distraction seems to me a bit pitiless ^^')

Comment: I [can't reproduce the problem](http://jsbin.com/yupegovu/1/) - it reports `3:  pippo` when the form is submitted.

Comment: Yea Igor and Quentin it's so. I tried to simplify a problem that was a bit more complicate that it seemed. It works if tested in the way i described it. My real problem it's another, i'll try to edit the question so to explain...

Comment: What is `myobject`? What is `myfunction`?

Comment: Of the three versions of this question you've asked, two error and none show the problem you are asking about. You need to provide code in the question that actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: The code is really too complicate, that's the problem. I thought it was not so important what myfunction or myobject were. Even if i change the variable in a callback it should get the value?

Comment: Assuming the callback gets called before you next inspect the variable. Since it clearly isn't, we'd need to see `myfunction` (and probably `myobject`) before can tell why it isn't.

Comment: If it can help i'm totally sure The callback get called before for The function trying to access that value is called when i push a submit button in a form and i know when tha callback gas been called for it logs a confirmation message. As soon as i can i'll try to post a simplified version of The callback. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is being executed from the top of the page as following :
`username` gets declared and set to `= null` -> `myFunction_1()` get's defined -> `myFunction_1()` gets called -> `username` gets set to `'pippo'` -> `console.logs` `"1: pippo"` -> `console.logs` `"2: pippo"` -> `myFunction_2()` get's defined -> `myFunction_2()` gets called -> `console.logs` `"3: pippo"` this happens in this sequence assuming that this code runs, which it does not in your case.

Assuming that `salvaUsername()` looks like `function salvaUsername(){ return username; }` username is null as it have never reached the point of assignment that happens in `myFunction_1()`. (It's actually surprising that output is not `undefined` but `null`).

**UPDATE**
In this case `myFunction_1()` never runs so `username` doesn't get set to `'pippo'` hence the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that code is not inside a function you haven't shown, `username` is a global variable. If you look at the value of `username` *before* calling `myFunction_1`, it will be `null`. If you call `myFunction_1`, then look at `username`, it will be `"pippo"` (and it will stay `"pippo"` until you do something not shown to change it). So if you're seeing `null` when you expect `"pippo"`, it tells you that either A) `myFunction_1` has not (yet?) been called, or B) You've done something since calling `myFunction_1` that set `username` back to `null`.